# Odoo filter problems

Tags: odoo

I create two class hr_comp and hr_applicant 
after i create lien between hr_comp and hr_applicant with the id comp_ids .
i create a widget in the model hr_applicant .

```html
<notebook colspane="1">
<page string="Compétences">
 <field name="comp_ids" colspan="4" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list">
  <tree string="compétence" editable="bottom">
   <field name="cat_id" />
   <!-- ici c'est l'appel de la fonction au niveau de l wml -->
   <field name="niv" />
   <field name="tech" />
  </tree>
 </field>
</page>
</notebook>
```

helpi want to create a filterr with the field cat_id but it doesnt work

Comment: Which is the filter you want to manage?

Comment: when i use the widget with name="comp_ids" odoo do not accepte to filter with the fierld name="cat_id" . but when i chage and remove the widget and work without it just have char field itr's work i dont know why !!! i use this code <record id="view_crm_case_jobs_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Jobs - Recruitment Search</field>
        <field name="model">hr.applicant</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Search Applicants">
                <field name="cat_id" string="co" />
           </search>
        </field>   </record>

Comment: you mean to say put a filter on o2m field?

Comment: yes that's what i mean